# Stream audio with MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ios, audio, stream

I'm trying play an audio stream from this site: http://www.radioteofilotoni.com.br/

I have:

```
MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://stream.jshost.com.br:1935/mobile/8056.stream/playlist.m3u8"]];
player.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
player.view.hidden = YES;
[self.view addSubview:player.view];
[player play];
```

Doesn't play anything, what's wrong? I can access this m3u8 link from Safari and play.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That URL doesn't return an audio stream-- it returns a text file that looks like this:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=52855
http://stream.jshost.com.br:1935/mobile/8056.stream/playlist.m3u8?wowzasessionid=1884064341
```

Loading *that* URL gives some more non-audio content, which you can use to eventually get an audio stream URL. It looks like Mobile Safari parses the text files to get the stream URL. You'll have to do that, too, because apparently `MPMoviePlayerController` doesn't do it.